# Why is my CSS3 animation not working?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS3 animation I want to do in chrome: (fadeIn, and change text color). I have a div element with class "divvy" and contains the text "Hello World". I don't know whyMy CSS is:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:0.3s;
    animation-duration:0.3s;


    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;

}


@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {color: black;}
    to {color: yellow;}
}


@keyframes example {
    from {color: black;}
    to {color: yellow;}
}

.divvy {
    color: black;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;

      -webkit-animation-name: example; 
          -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 6s;
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="divvy fade-in">Hello World</div>
```

The inclusion of webkit-animation-name also appears to make the text disappear for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me.  You can run the code below to see it working:

```css
fade-in {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:0.3s;
    animation-duration:0.3s;


    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;

}


@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {color: black; opacity:0;}
    to {color: yellow; opacity:1;}
}


@keyframes example {
    from {color: black; opacity:0;}
    to {color: yellow; opacity:1;}
}

.divvy {
    color: black;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;

      -webkit-animation-name: example; 
          -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="divvy fade-in">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: I don't think i see the fade-in effect.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on?  Working fine on 41.

Comment: I've edited the code incase you were referring to fading in terms of invisible to visible.  I added opacity:0; and opacity:1; to the keyframes.  Previously only the color was fading in from black to yellow.

Comment: Is there a way to stagger, such that .divvy changes fades in first, then starts changing color with CSS3 only?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish similar effects using the CSS3 `transition` property and a bit of JS (I used jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".divvy").first().removeClass("fade-in");
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.divvy {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 4s;
}
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divvy fade-in">Hello, World</div>
```